# ROS2 one action client calling multiple servers

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, action, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to call multiple action servers with a single client, however, with the current `rclcpp` implementation server name is only passed in the constructor, so the only option currently seems to be maintaining a number of client instances with dedicated names. It would seem that having one instance and calling multiple servers should be the optimal way of doing it, maybe by passing an additional argument to `async_send_goal` function. Am I missing something?

Are there any ways of achieving this with the current implementation of `rclcpp`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379982/ros2-one-action-client-calling-multiple-servers/) by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is not, nor was there that ability in  ROS 1. It has to setup pubs/subs behind the scene to exchange information so the client will need to be unique per server instance.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1